# Extremely Slow Adding to a list of objects belonging to a parent object using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, list, lazy-loading

Currently I'm having some major performance issues when performing "AddRange" to a list of objects in entity first.

Essentially I have a thread object that contains a large list of post objects; when trying to add additional items to this list of objects it takes an extremely long time.

Below is my code:

```
public void AddItemsToList(List<Post> posts, int threadId)
{
    Thread thread = context.Threads.Find(threadID);
    if (thread != null) {
            //do stuff to posts
            thread.Posts.AddRange(posts);
            //When thread.Posts.AddRange is called LazyLoading queries 
            // the context for thread.Posts which has >+ 50000 items
            }
}

public class Thread {
    public int threadID { get; set;}
    public string threadTitle { get; set;}
    public virtual List<Post> posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    ////etc...
}
```

What I assume is happening:

1. I'm creating a list of posts
2. I'm calling the parent thread that contains a list Posts - lazy loading *doesn't pull in all the posts from the object which is fine.
3. I'm attempting to add my **new** list of Posts to the thread's list of posts which in turn causes EF to grab **all** items in the large list of Posts BEFORE adding the new ones which is causing the slow down.

What I would ideally like to do is simply **add** to the list as opposed to grabbing the full list then adding it.

Comment: What type of relationship do you have between the entities in question?

Comment: Have you set LazyLoading to false? If not it will bring all related data if you want to get them as list and please, provide code to get help

Comment: add the new post directly to posts DbSet, and then call savechanges.

Comment: With current sample there is no way to see why there is any "lazy loading" at all as all objects seem to be `List<T>` - if you looking for help please make sure you sample actually demonstrates the problem.